# Passing String Arguments to kill() in C

Tags: c, process, signals, kill

I am looking for a way to pass Arguments as String to the Function kill in C (man 2 kill), because the Signal depends on the OS. So the User puts in what the Programm should send(For Example SIGUSR1,..) and i want to submit it. Through kill(pid,USR_INPUT);

My Error

```
Invalid Argument
```

Where I use it:

```
kill(pid,name);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can't. The `kill` function just doesn't support calling it like that. You read the man page so you should know that already. Why would you ignore what the man page says that the second parameter needs to be?

Comment: so do i have to implement this for every os. That seems to be wrong

Comment: @PeterNeuman Considering that `kill()` *itself* is not C but POSIX, I don't see how you can expect this to work "on every os".

Comment: At this methods: int sigaction(int signum, const struct sigaction *act,
              struct sigaction *oldact);

It works fine if i m using it as : int sigaction(SIGKILL,...

Comment: @PeterNeuman kill() and sigation() do *completely* different things. So, not sure about your comparison. Even then, they both work with signal numbers as `int`s (not strings).

Comment: @PeterNeuman Millions of other people have used `kill` just fine without string support. So perhaps the question is why you think you need it. If you really do then surely it is a simple matter to have a wrapper that maps between the string and the signal number. And you don't have to implement "for every OS". The same wrapper should work for any POSIX OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply not possible.

`kill(2)` doesn't accept string (second) argument for the signal. It sounds a bit iffy that you had to handle signals inputted as strings. If you really need to do this, you can convert your string input to an integer form by comparing it with the list of signals you are interested in:

```
if (strcmp(sig_str, "SIGINT") == 0) {
   sig_num = SIGINT;
} else if (sig_str, "SIGTERM") == 0) {
   sig_num = SIGTERM;
} else if ...

...

kill(pid, sig_num);
```

Comment: okay fixed it if i am writing int Signal=SIGUSR1 and not char * Signal=SIGUSR;